# Java SWT: widgetSelected vs widgetDefaultSelected

Tags: java, user-interface, event-handling, swt

For example I want to execute something when user clicks on a button. Which do I use? The documentation didn't appear to make it very clear

**UPDATE**

A quick test shows that Widget Selected is triggered but not Default Selected.

**In `TasksView.main()`**

```
TasksView view = new TasksView(shell, SWT.None);
TasksController controller = new TasksController(view);
```

**In `TasksController`**

```
public class TasksController extends ControllerAbstract {
    protected TasksView view;

    public TasksController(TasksView view) {
        this.view = view;
        view.addTaskListener(new AddTaskListener());
    }

    protected class AddTaskListener implements SelectionListener {

        @Override
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("Default Selected");

        }

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("Widget Selected");

        }

    }
}
```

btw, Did I do MVC correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `widgetSelected`.  In fact, all the better is to simply extend `SelectionAdapter` and only  override the `widgetSelected` method and completely ignore `widgetDefaultSelected`.

Answer (score 4):

`SelectionListener.widgetDefaultSelected(e)` has a toolkit dependent behavior. I usually just invoke `SelectionListener.widgetSelected(...)`. (Note that this is not the default in `SelectionAdapter.widgetDefaultSelected(e)` - you will have to do this yourself.