# widgetDefaultSelected() method never triggered?

Tags: java, events, radio-button, swt

Suppose I have two radio buttons, I want one to be default selected, and I want the `SelectionListener` to do some action.

When I tried the obvious way it didn't work:

```
Button button = new Button(parent, SWT.RADIO) ;
button.setSelection(true) ;

button.addSelectionListener( new SelectionAdapter() {
    public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e){
        doAction() ;
    }
}) ;
```

`doAction()` is never triggered...

Can anybody explain why the `SelectionEvent` for the default selection is never triggered?

Comment: It's platform-dependent action, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254310/java-swt-widgetselected-vs-widgetdefaultselected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example, on some platforms default selection occurs in a List when the user double-clicks an item or types return in a Text. On some platforms, the event occurs when a mouse button or key is pressed. On others, it happens when the mouse or key is released. The exact key or mouse gesture that causes this event is platform specific.

The [JavaDoc](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/events/SelectionListener.html#widgetDefaultSelected%28org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent%29) says it all. It's a platform-dependent action that might occur on some `Control`s. AFAIK, the `Button` with `SWT.CHECK` is not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

change your code to:

```
button.addSelectionListener( new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e){
        doAction() ;
    }
}) ;
```

and avoid using `widgetDefaultSelected()`.

Comment: I'm using "setSelection". Why doesn't it call "widgetSelected" ? Is there any way to call it ?